# Typing in react form input causes focus loss and re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code, which results in the focus being lost as soon a key is pressed in the firm password field. Exploration suggests the form is being re-rendered, as a result of `setState` but I am not sure why or how to fix.

```
import React from 'react';
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
    // code omitted 
});

class ResetPasswordForm extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            key: this.props.key,
            password: '',
            passwordConfirm: ''        
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    } 

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // TODO
    }

    renderField(field) {
        const name = field.name;
        const id = field.id || name;
        const label = strings[name];
        const fieldType = field.type || 'text';
        const placeholder = strings[name + '-placeholder'];

        // TODO
        let touched;
        let error;

        return <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor={id}>{label}:</label>
            <input id={id}  type={fieldType} placeholder={placeholder} name={name} onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state[name]}
                className="form-control"/> {touched && error && <div className="error bg-warning">{error}</div>}
        </div>
    }

    render() {
        const Field = this.renderField.bind(this);

        return (
            <div>
            <h2>{strings['title']}</h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                {this.props.statusText && <div className='alert alert-info'>
                    {this.props.statusText}
                </div>}

                <Field
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    />

                <Field
                    name="passwordConfirm"
                    type="password"/>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input 
                        type="submit"
                        name="Submit"
                        defaultValue={strings['submit']}
                        />
                </div>

            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Edit: Further experimenting suggest that 'Field' lines are causing the issue and replacing them with the following resolves the issue:

```
{this.renderField({
    name: "password",
    type: "password"
})}

{this.renderField({
    name: "passwordConfirm",
    type: "password"
})}
```

Alternatively, in the constructor I can do:

```
this.renderField = this.renderField.bind(this);
```

and then in the render function I can do:

```
const Field = this.renderField;
```

While these approaches work, I am not sure the exact impact of the change sin terms of React. If anyone can explain, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the error:

```
const Field = this.renderField.bind(this);
```

renderField(field) accept the object parameter(field) and you never pass it. So you need to pass it

```
const Field = this.renderField.bind(this, { name: "password", type: "password"});
```

Comment: That doesn't really explain what is going on. In digging I have found two alternate solutions (see question), but I am not sure I quite understand why they work, beyond the fact that they do.

Answer (score 0):

Each time `render` is executed, you generate new function-Component with `this.renderField.bind(this)`. In this case, React's reconciliation algorithm will treat this as a difference, and the entire subtree will be rendered from scratch.

From [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types):

> **Elements Of Different Types**
>
> Whenever the root elements have different types, React will tear down
>   the old tree and build the new tree from scratch. Going from  to
>   , or from  to , or from  to  - any
>   of those will lead to a full rebuild.

Here is a screencap of DevTools elements inspector, which illustrates DOM updates in both cases

1. *Original* (Field is generated on each render)
   You can see that the `<div>` node is collapsed and rendered from scratch => focus is lost.
   [image]
2. *Fixed* (`this.renderField({...})` is used)
   Only `"value"` field is updated, the rest of DOM is intact => focus is preserved
   [image]